# Excel VBA: 2 dimensional array search, check to see if cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of cells in excel with names of people on the left column and certain tasks (as numbers) on the top row, like a two dim array.  All I want to do is be able to search for the name and numbered task to see if that cell is blank or not in VBA.

In the excel sheet I can use a formula like:
=ISBLANK(VLOOKUP("Bob", A2:AE33,3,FALSE))

which works, but can't seem to find do this in VBA.

I've tried to just do something like this:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.ISBLANK(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(studentComboBox.Value, Range("A2:AE33"), i + 2, False))
```

But it gives an error like "object does not support this property or method". Any help appreciated.

Comment: A relatively simple method would be to drop that formula into a cell offsheet where you can't see it normally.  Then grab the value of that cell from VBA to get the calculated result from the formula.

Comment: Doug's answer is the right approach, but for completeness you can alternatively use `ActiveSheet.Evaluate(yourFormula)` where `yourFormula` is a variable containing a valid worksheet formula (including the "=").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have access to ISBLANK via WorksheetFunction.  Try:    `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(studentComboBox.Value, Range("A2:AE33"), i + 2, False)=""`